# Separate payment configuration for Apple Music and iCloud Storage

Tags: icloud, paypal, apple-id

I'm using Apple Music and a 50 GB iCloud storage tier. At the moment I pay for both the services with my PayPal account configured as the payment method for my Apple ID.

My Company wants to pay for the iCloud storage for me now. The problem is, that I don't know if it is possible to change only the payment method of the iCloud storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a separate payment method setup for Apple Music and iCloud storage.

There is a single unified [payment method configuration](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201266) for consuming all the services made available by Apple for an Apple ID.

You can request your company to [add funds to your PayPal account](https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-add-money-to-my-paypal-balance-faq1348) or ask them to [add funds to your Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208687).